# Printing negative int as long produces wrong result

Tags: c

I'm compiling the following C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int nEndIndex = -1;
    printf("nEndIndex : %ld\n", nEndIndex);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it with GCC 4.2.4 as follows:

```
[kartika@alto ~/junk]$ gcc -o test test.c
[kartika@alto ~/junk]$ ./test
nEndIndex : 4294967295
[kartika@alto ~/junk]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.2.4
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I thought since `long` is bigger than an `int` it shouldn't be a problem to use `%ld`. And since both of them are `signed` why am I getting this output?

Comment: It prints -1 for me. gcc version 4.6.3

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy: Only by luck. The behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the argument (after promotion, which doesn't apply in this case) *must* match the type expected for the format string; otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Passing an `int` to a function expecting a `long int` is usually permitted, and causes an implicit conversion. But for a variadic function like `printf`, the compiler doesn't know what type to convert the argument to.

The behavior is undefined, which means that quite literally anything can happen (including, if you're *unlucky*, the code appearing to work "correctly"). In practice, let's assume that `int` is 32 bits and `long` is 64 bits (those sizes vary from system to system). `printf` might grab 64 bits of data from the stack, 32 bits from your argument and another 32 bits of garbage; it will then print that data *assuming* that it's a `long int` object (because that's what you told it via the format string).

Use `%d` for an `int` argument, `%ld` for a `long int` argument.

Comment: I know I should have used `%d` it's just that I expected `long int` to work flawlessly with `int`

Comment: @KartikAnand: Why did you expect that?

Comment: Well because `long int` is bigger than an `int` and it shouldn't have had any problem. As in we expect `unsigned long` to work with `void*` because of having the same width.

Comment: @KartikAnand: I'm afraid your expectations were incorrect. `printf` will simply *assume* that you've passed it a `long int` argument, because that's what you told it with the format string. You actually passed an `int` argument. If, for example, `int` is 32 bits and `long` is 64 bits, it might grab 64 bits of data off the stack -- 32 from your argument plus 32 bits of garbage. Or it could do literally anything else. Incidentally, there is no guarantee that `unsigned long` and `void*` have the same width, and they're not interchangeable; if you want to print a `void*` with `printf`, use `%p`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is not declared as `long int` . The declaration should be `long int nEndIndex = -1;`

Comment: *Or* the `printf` format should be `%d` rather than `%ld`.